# Contour plot with an error function

Tags: graphing-functions, error-function

I got trouble with the Contourplot function. Probably due to the precision of an error function. The function is wish to plot is

$\frac{1}{2}+4.47e^{-1-0.02x^2+25\gamma^2-1+\frac{\gamma^2}{8\sigma^2}}\Big(1+\mathrm{Erf}\big(\frac{0.14/\gamma-7.14\gamma}{\sqrt{2}}\big)\Big) $

as soon as $\gamma$ becomes too large, then the contour plot breaks down. My best guess is, that it have something to do with the error funtion which Matematic approx to $-1$. I have tried to set the precision by N[f(x),n], but without any luck.

Thanks in advance, ladies and gentlemen.

Comment: Is $\sigma$ constant?

Comment: Precise the value of $\sigma$ and the ranges you want to cover. This will help.

Comment: Sorry, yes, $\sigma$ is constant. And, for completeness, $\sigma=0.7$. When you say "the range you want to cover" do you mean i should use the PlotRange function? This i have tried but it don't seem to help

Comment: I was asking for the range of $x$ and $\gamma$